# What does “to be last in someone's line” mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, jokes

In a social media post, the following was written:

```
Dude, where are you?

At the hostel, studying dad
Where are you?

At the beer shop, I'm last in your line.
Buy two beers for me too.

 ok dad
```

I don't get this meme as I don't understand a part of it, what does being last in someone's line mean?

I didn't manage to find the answer on the internet too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the student is getting “busted” by their dad, who sees that the student is really ahead of him in a line to buy beer (not actually studying at the hostel, as the student claims).

Comment: Yes, the student is lying about where he is.

Comment: Ohhh ok! I understand this is not an expression but he IS actually in the same line as his dad! Thanks!